# How to fix 'SQL Configurartion Manager'?

Tags: sql-server, configurationmanager

I'm have a problem with sql server configuration manager send the error "Cannot connect to WMI Provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable. Note that you can only manage SQL Sever 2005 and later servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager.
not valid class [0x80041010]"

Are 2 instances installed in the server, I've tried:

1.- Edith regedit in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT{73E709EA-5D93-4B2E-BBB0-99B7938DA9E4} add user "evereyone" with full control.

2.- Restart server.

3.- Add full control to user everyone in the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\"

4.- Start cmd how administrator and execute: mofcomp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

5.- But return error:
"MOF file has been successfully parsed
Storing data in the repository…
An error occurred while processing item 10 defined on lines 73 – 79 in file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof:
Compiler returned error 0x80070005Error Number: 0x80070005, Facility: Win32
Description: Access is denied."

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the same issue, and would run this at the command line:

mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

seems you left off the .exe in your example, could that be it? This fix has worked multiple times for me on multiple versions (while obviously changing the path to the appropriate version).

Best of luck!

Comment: i tried with mofcomp.exe but didn't work, this solution it's work in many server but thats server only have 1 instance installed and i cant unistall the instance, because one is the distribution of a transactional replication, but thanks.

Comment: hmm, brainstorming here... 

Install a new instance, script out then pause replication (both sides), quickly detach/reattach the db's on the new instance, run the replication scripts, restore the Distribution db, then restart replication? You'd have to update the subscribers to the new location but I'm 98% certain you don't have to blow the subscription away totally just update it.

Else you can do the same thing with moving the DB's over, script out the publication, update the subscriber's to point to new instance, and reinitialize the subscribers from a snapshot.

Comment: yeah, that not a good option because te publisher all time is sending and purge info, so the subscriptor save all historic, so i can't do a snapshot, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION/WORKAROUND](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/05/20/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-connect-wmi-provider-not-permission-server-unreachable/)

Since it was an access denied error, I downloaded and run a process monitor and looked for access denied. We found below interesting key related to WMI.

```
svchost.exe 1023 RegOpenKey HKCR\CLSID\{73E709EA-5D93-4B2E-BBB0-99B7938DA9E4}\LocalServer32 ACCESS DENIED
```

Now, we know the key which is showing access denied.

[image]

SQL SERVER - Configuration Manager - Cannot Connect to WMI Provider. You Do Not Have Permission or The Server is Unreachable mof-comp-02 
We checked permission and found that Administrator has full permission on the above key. But access denied was for Network Service account so we added Network service on the above key and then ran the above command (MOFCOMP) again. Since permissions were fixed, we could run the above command successfully. After that SQL Server Configuration Manager just opened fine and we were able to manage the SQL related services successfully.